# Magento. Unable to rewrite Address model

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite Magento Address Model but I'm going crazy with this. My config.xml rewrite section looks like this

```
<models>
    <customer>
         <rewrite>
             <customer>MyNam_MyMod_Model_Customer</customer>
             <address>MyNam_MyMod_Customer_Model_Address</address>
         </rewrite>
    </customer>
</models>
```

and my class looks like:

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/Model/Address.php';
class MyNam_MyMod_Customer_Model_Address extends Mage_Customer_Model_Address
{


public function validate() {
    parent::validate();
}
}
```

When I load address form I get the following error: *Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /var/www/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Edit.php on line 53*

I noticed that edit block is unable to load *customer/address* model

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

i hope  in class address `MyNam_MyMod_Customer_Model_Address` ,i should be  **MyNam_MyMod_Model_Address**

```
<models>
    <customer>
         <rewrite>
             <customer>MyNam_MyMod_Model_Customer</customer>
             <address>MyNam_MyMod_Model_Address</address>
         </rewrite>
    </customer>
</models>
```

let me know, if you have any issue...

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the line `require_once 'Mage/Customer/Model/Address.php';`
You don't need this because classes are loaded automatically.
The rest of your code looks correct. Did you clear your var/cache folder?